# Consequence of extending/inheriting 3rd party Django app models

Tags: django, database-design, django-models

I have set up the 3rd party app in my Django project.  The model in question is the Tag model. Just like how SO has Tag text box underneath the question, I want to create multiple of them. Different classes if you may.

Example: College_tag, department_tag, subject_tag and so on.

I know that modifying 3rd party app is not a good idea so I am going to be extending the 3rd party APP's Tag model

The "thread" model which is also in 3rd party app has manytomany with Tag.

The result I require is "thread" model should have manytomany with College_tag, department_tag, subject_tag

Also the searching should be efficient. Before, I could do a search on tags. Now I should be able to do it on colleges, departments and subjects.

> 1. How should I design this?
> 2. This should be done without touching the 3rd party code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't it work to just make another model that has a one-to-one relation with `Tag` ? ie.

```
from django.db import models

class TagProfile(models.Model):
    tag = models.OneToOneField('taggit.tag')
    # add your custom fields here
```

No need to hack the third party app's model code nor database schema so far.

KISS

Comment: I see but Consider a case where I have provided a text box for tag_a. When user is entering something, a drop down of suggesstions only related to tag_a should be displayed. Similar requirement when searching a particular class. Won't this get complicated if I do this way?  Thanks

Comment: I don't see how this could be a problem. Could you elaborate ? Maybe improve your question ? Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I was doing a bit more studying and stumbled upon https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance

This also creates one to one relation. Can I use this? I can create multiple Tag objects and new tables and 
maintain them just like how the requirement is..

Comment: You could do that. In that case, you might also want to use something like [django-polymodels](https://github.com/charettes/django-polymodels) which provides a nice API to query on model multiple inheritance.

Comment: My bad, I wanted to inform you about [django-model-utils](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/managers.html#inheritancemanager) which provides the nice manager with `select_subclasses()`.

Comment: Great articles! Thanks! Although, if I use django-polymodels,  I will have to make 3rd party Tag Model a PolyModel. Similarly, using Django-model-utils will also require me to make changes to 3rd party code. Is that alright?

Comment: Well you could add the InheritanceManager by monkey patching.

Comment: That would mean it will have 2 Managers. One its own (TagManager) and InheritanceManager.

Comment: Exactly, this would give you a manager for use with select_subclasses() which can be very handy in some situations.

Comment: Thanks! I have read that monkey patching might not be a full-time, scalable solution.
I was thinking of doing something like this,

class Tag(models.Model):
  ...
  objects = TagManager()
  my_manager = InheritanceManager() # My line of code

I thought this would easily maintainable going forward but still there is a risk.

Comment: Yeah, the most maintainable solution is to make relations one-to-one or foreign key from your own models, that's for sure !! I've tried everything xD

Answer (score 2):

```
from django.db import models
from YourTagModel import Tag
from YourThreadModel import Thread

class College_tag(Tag):
    pass
    #all the fields in the model Tag will be inherited


class Department_tag(Tag):
    pass

class MyThreadModel(Thread):
    College_tag_relation = models.ManyToManyField(College_tag)
    department_tag_relation = models.ManyToManyField(Department_tag)
```

This creates a relation in your database mapping to the Tag model objects similar to a one to one field. But django treats it as you would expect inheritance to work

Comment: Thanks! One point i forgot to mention, Thread model is also in 3rd party app so I cannot really modify it like shown above.

Comment: You can extend a new class MyThreadModel(Thread): instead of the class thread(models.Model): and it should work just fine